# How do I reload files in WinMerge after making changes?

Tags: winmerge

I have two files named `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. After using WinMerge to compare both files, I use Notepad++ to edit `file2.txt` and save my changes. These new changes don't appear in WinMerge unless I re-select both files for a new comparison.

Is there a way to reload files in WinMerge after making changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is there a way to reload files in WinMerge after making changes?

You can press <kbd>F5</kbd>  (refresh).

Alternatively configure WinMerge to perform an "Automatic rescan".

Check your WinMerge settings in ***Edit → Options → Editor → Automatic rescan***.

> 4.1. Rescanning files
>
> By default, the Automatic rescan option is enabled in the Editor page
>   of WinMerge options. Rescanning keeps your your compare and merge
>   operations up to date. **Without rescanning, WinMerge differences does
>   not detect changes that might occur to files while you are comparing
>   them, for example in an external editor.**
>
> Rescanning occurs when you perform certain actions (like merging a
>   difference or editing a file) during a file compare. If a file has
>   changed, WinMerge displays a dialog advising you that another
>   application has updated the file, and asks whether you want to reload
>   the file.
>
> Click Yes to reload the file before proceeding, or No to ignore the
>   changes and work with the earlier loaded version of the file.
>
> **If Automatic rescan is disabled, or if you suspect that a file might have changed, we strongly advise that you run Refresh before
>   performing any merge operation: click Edit → Refresh or the Refresh
>   button toolbar button, or press F5.**
>
> If a merge result looks incorrect, click Edit → Undo or press Ctrl+Z
>   to undo the merge. Then rescan the files and try merging again.

(emphasis mine)

Source [Comparing and merging text files - WinMerge 2.12 Manual](http://manual.winmerge.org/Compare_files.html)

Comment: There wasn't a menu entry for *Edit → Refresh*. However, both the `F5` shortcut and *Automatic rescan* option worked as expected.

Comment: "Another application has updated file ... since WinMerge scanned it last time." Reload, yes or no. That's the prompt you get when you hit the F5 key after a file changed. If no changes, F5 is silently ignored. If there were changes but you answer "No" you don't get another chance, F5 is ignored after that too.